# Is there any difference between `*x` and `x*`?

Tags: rascal

I found in some demo code, both `*x` and `x*` are used.  Sometimes, the star is also used on types, like `*int xs`.  In the help, only the pattern `Var*` is documented.  Is there any difference between putting the star before or after a pattern variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. The answer is both yes and no:

- Yes: The post-fix `*` is deprecated, since it triggers syntactical ambiguity with post-fix transitive closure in some weird contexts on the expression side of things. This does not happen in patterns, but for consistency we want to have the prefix `*` mean "splat" in patterns and "splice" in expressions, as dual operators, and remove the post-fix `*` to avoid confusion.
- No: when applied to a variable in a pattern they will have the same semantics.

So, please use the prefix `+` and prefix `*` when possible to avoid upgrade pain in the future when we remove postfix `*` and `+` from the language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But I guess you want to swap "No" and "Yes", don't you.  To be sure I understand it correctly, for _cluster_ in pattern and _splice_ in expression, prefix `+` and `*` should be used, because the postfix syntax will be reserved _only_ for closure operations on relations.